# What went wrong with my upgrade to Maverick 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, upgrade

Since I have upgraded my working Lucid PC to Maverick I am unable to log in as a normal user. I can only login as root. If I log in as a normal user the log in screen disappears and reappears with the sound effects. If I type the wrong password then I get authorization failure and back to the log in screen as normal. Even then as root if I try to run some programs it will return to the login screen. The display seems to be fine - it is the onboard S3 - no special drivers.

Please help - I am scared to upgrade my other machines!!

Comment: This looks as if some incompatible program from your Lucid installation crashed the X-Server.

Comment: was this a true upgrade, or new install using old home partition?

Comment: True upgrade using alternate cd. I used update manager to update everything and then ra the upgrade from the cd.

Answer (score 3):

This could be related to an application or Driver.  I have seen Compiz and other programs crash X in the past, so to start with I would start to disable auto run applications.

As you can't get a desktop, start a new session in Failsafe GNOME mode, using the dropdown for sessions, once you have selected your name.

[image: GNOME]

Then follow the instructions on this [Link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1067101) to disable your auto start applications.

If you have Compiz enabled, follow this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1406936) to see how to disable that too.

Have you tried creating a new user and seeing if the issue affects that account too?

Comment: Yes I did create a new user and that worked until I rebooted the computer.

Comment: what did you enable on the user between its creation and the reboot

Comment: Ah I forgot - when logged in as root I am unable to add or edit users using users admin tool. The window sit s there doing nothing and all greyed out. I had to use adduser in the terminal.